# Fetching daylerees colour schemes for PHPStorm from Github

Tags: python

I wanted to download all colour schemes for `phpstorm` and was too lazy to do it manually so I wrote a little script for it in python, because why not.

This is my very first `Python` script and I'm still learning through tutorials and what not.

Things it does:

1. Asks to input the path where to save the files
2. If the destination folder does not exist, creates it
3. Makes sure the the path ends with '/'
4. Instantiates a crawler instance
5. Crawler fetches the initial JSON payload
6. It loops over the items to check whether an item is a file or a directory
7. If it is a file, downloads it. If a folder, instantiates a new crawler instance with that directory path
8. Before downloading the files, it checks if the file exists already and prints the messages accordingly.

Things I can already see that I will go back and improve:

1. Make passing the link dynamic, instead of hard coding.
2. Implement a better path checking / validation.
3. use try / except methods instead where applicable.

And the code:

```
import urllib
import json
import time
import os
import re


class Crawler:
    def __init__(self, url, path):
        self.url = url
        self.path = path
        self.counter = 0
        self.total_files = 0

    def crawl(self):
        self.get_contents()

    def get_contents(self):
        response = urllib.urlopen(self.url).read()
        collection = json.loads(response)
        self.total_files = len(collection)
        for data in collection:
            if data.get('type') == 'file':
                self.download(data.get('name'), data.get('download_url'))
            elif data.get('type') == 'dir':
                dir_crawler = Crawler(data.get('url'), self.path)
                print('\nFound a directory. Pausing the main download and crawling the directory - ' + data.get(
                    'name') + '\n')
                dir_crawler.crawl()
                print('\n' + data.get('name') + ' directory is done. Continuing from where I left off.\n')
            time.sleep(1)

    def download(self, name, link):
        if name and not os.path.exists(self.path + name):
            download = urllib.URLopener()
            download.retrieve(link, self.path + name)
            self.counter += 1
            print('Downloading ' + name + ' (' + str(self.counter) + ' out of ' + str(self.total_files) + ')')
        else:
            print('File: ' + name + ' already exists in ' + self.path)


download_location = raw_input(
    "Where would you like me to save the files? (e.g. ./ or ../ or ./themes/ or /path/to/folder): ")
if download_location and re.match(r'.+/$', download_location):
    if not os.path.exists(download_location):
        os.mkdir(download_location)
    crawler = Crawler('https://api.github.com/repos/daylerees/colour-schemes/contents/jetbrains',
                      download_location)
    crawler.crawl()
    print('\n\nAll done. Themes have been saved into ' + download_location +
          '. Thank you for your cooperation. Have a nice day.')
else:
    print('The path must end with a forward slash.')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `os.path.exists` you may want to specifically use `os.path.isdir` and `isfile`. `isdir` checks if the path matches an existing folder, and `isfile` checks for files. It is possible for the path you pass to be valid but not of the correct type for your purposes, which would be a significant error for your folders as you then have invalid paths that you'd attempt to download to.

Also to make it easier on your user, I would wrap the main code in a `while` loop so that if they enter an invalid path the program doesn't exist the program still doesn't exit:

```
while True:
    download_location = raw_input(
        "Where would you like me to save the files? (e.g. ./ or ../ or ./themes/ or /path/to/folder): ")
    if download_location and re.match(r'.+/$', download_location):
        if not os.path.isdir(download_location):
            os.mkdir(download_location)
        crawler = Crawler('https://api.github.com/repos/daylerees/colour-schemes/contents/jetbrains',
                          download_location)
        crawler.crawl()
        print('\n\nAll done. Themes have been saved into ' + download_location +
              '. Thank you for your cooperation. Have a nice day.')
        break
    else:
        print('The path must end with a forward slash.')
```

Putting `break` after your `print` call will end the infinite loop once the code has  successfully run but otherwise it will keep asking for input.

Also no need for regex. Python has a `str.endswith` function that detects if a string ends with a certain string. So you could just use:

```
    if download_location.endswith('/'):
```

`raw_input` will at least return a string, so you can just call this function on `download_location`. If it's an empty string it will return `False` since an empty string doesn't end with `'/'`.